# Fastest cavalry unit in Bannerlord

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

In Bannerlord, what cavalry unit moves the fastest in a battle over perfectly flat terrain with time to get to its full speed, also, which calvalry unit moves fastest on the map? (If there even is a speed discrepancy between different cavalry units on the mao)

Note: I am only counting units that aren’t companions, lords, the player, or the players family.

Answer (score 0):

It's either the Aserai Vanguard Faris or the Aserai Mameluke Heavy Cavalry. I notice that both of them are very fast compared to others. I think that the Aserai is the fastest faction.